# Sharepoint 2013 Online Document Set

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, share

Is It possible to move/copy Doc Set from library A to library B (same siteCol),
with Workflow ?

I created a workflow with SPD 13, but was warned that it is not possible!

Have I done wrong? Or is it impossible? Is there other ways to move the whole Doc Set?

Answer (score 0):

With SPD designer and document set..mm guess you have to write REST scripts in your 2013 designer workflow for copying the folders, I dont see any other way.

Comment: As far as I know its not  available in the REST (API) for moving or copying a folder to another library.